Почему на сайте созданном на wordpress+woocommerce дублируется категория?
Есть сайт с товарами. На нём есть вот такая категория:
https://evroflag24.ru/category-product/reklamnye-stojki
Всё окей. Но она же дублируется вот по таким URL:
https://evroflag24.ru/category-product/nanesenie-logotipa/sublimacionnaja-pechat-na-tkani/product/product/product/product/product/product/product/product/reklamnye-stojki
https://evroflag24.ru/category-product/nanesenie-logotipa/sublimacionnaja-pechat-na-tkani/reklamnye-stojki
https://evroflag24.ru/category-product/nanesenie-logotipa/reklamnye-stojki
Как сделать так, чтобы эта категория была доступна только по одному URL, а дублирующие URL удалились?

Доступность по урлам вида сайт/category/что_угодно/хоть_тыщу_раз/название_рубрики (относится не только к к рубрикам и WC-категориям, но и почти ко всем сущностям) - это давняя бага ВП.  Но к сожалению разработчики считают что достаточно каноникала для лечения этого.
У тебя он стоит и поэтому в ПС дублей быть не должно (особенно если не ставить левые беклинки как ты сделал в вопросе)

Как сделать так, чтобы эта категория была доступна только по одному
URL, а дублирующие URL удалились?

Если очень хочется то для каждой категории можно прописать редирект. Но это костыль, который всё равно не решит проблему окончательно со всеми сущностями.
ЗЫ. возможно какие-то сео-плагины это могут, тут я не знаю. Я этим не заморачиваюсь. Есть куда более важные моменты при разработке ИМ.
